# Changing characters in assembly (nasm)

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Using C file in assembly (NASM)

So I have a c function that receives a letter and an integer, and shifts the letter by the number of integer. So if the letter is "a" and the int is 3 will return "d".

Then I have my assembly code that has a string and calls the subroutine "shift" which calls this c function. My shift subroutine needs to iterate through my string sending each letter to my c function and then changing in my string with the letter that returns.

However when I run and print the new string it only prints a J. I am not even sure where it is coming from because no matter the number of shifts will always print J. I think the problem is with the size of my registers.
Not sure, please help.

Also, I put some outputs in my c function and what I see is that is going the first letter fine, however the integer is not correct, also when I put some printf there I get segmentation fault.

The c function:

```c
char changeLetter(char letter, int numOfShifts) 
{
    return letter + numOfShifts;
}
```

My assembly code:

```nasm
global _start
extern changeLetter

section .data

format db '%d',0
format3 db "%s ",0
message: db "Please give the number of shifts :",10,0
message5: db "Message is :",10,0
message2: db "Encrypted message is :",10,0
original: db "Hello World.",10,0

len1: equ $ - original

section .bss
numShift: resq 1

section .text
global main

main:
mov rsi, message5
call messages

mov rsi, original
call messages

mov rsi, message
call messages

call scan


mov r8,original ;moving to my register message to be shifted
mov rsi, len1 ;length of message
mov rbx, numShift
call shift ;calling subroutine   

mov rsi, r8 ;moving new message to my register to be printed
call messages

ret


shift:

mov rdx, rsi ;rdx length of string 
mov rcx,0

loop: cmp rcx, rdx
jge done
mov rdi, [r8 +rcx] ;character to be shifted
mov rsi, rbx ;number of shifts
  
call changeLetter

mov [r8 + rcx], rax ;replace the character
inc rcx
jmp loop

done:
ret


messages:
mov rdi,format3
mov rdx,rsi
mov rax,0
call printf
ret

scan: ;getting the year from user   
mov rdi, format ;first parameter
mov rsi, numShift ;second parameter   
mov rax, 0 ;no xmm registers   
call scanf ;calling c function to get input from user
ret
```

Comment: If your characters are bytes you should write bytes, not quadwords. Instead of `mov [r8 + rcx], rax` you should use `mov [r8 + rcx], al`. Unlikely to fix your program entirely though.

Comment: Where is `rcx` supposed to be initialised?